# I don't understand why the css and the images are not seen in phplist

Tags: css, image, loading, phplist

I've installed phplist in a folder in public_html folder in my site

```
http://www.parcuri.ro/news/
```

It's working, but the images and the css are not "used"

The paths in config file are

```
$pageroot = '/news';
$adminpages = '/news/admin';
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to access your [css](http://www.parcuri.ro/news/styles/phplist.css) or [images](http://www.parcuri.ro/news/images/masthead.png), I am getting redirected to your homepage. I am assuming this is your 404 page so the CSS and Images dont "exist". This means your file paths are wrong or you have not saved the css/images in the right area.

Perhaps your images/css are stored in `http://www.parcuri.ro/styles` rather than `http://www.parcuri.ro/news/styles`.

Comment: They can't be or else they would be accessible, maybe they are stored in sub folders or something? find your phplist.css and link me to it

Comment: i have this in my site's .htacces: `RewriteRule (.*)\.html$   $1.php
RewriteRule .*/(.*)\.css$   style/$1.css
RewriteRule .*/images/(.*)$   images/$1
RewriteRule .*/(.*)\.js$   js/$1.js`

Comment: It isn't about the filepaths on your html page, they look correct. The media isn't stored where it is expected.

Comment: fixed. the problem was with .htacces. I've put RewriteEngine Off in .htacces from news folder